# Can't access entirely shared HDD on Windows Server

Tags: network, macos

So i have a whole entire network on windows, with a WS2012 R2 installed as Domain Controller, a few hiccups here and there but everything is working

I recently added a 6tb disk, and shared it all, it's pretty much their profiles disk.

Thing is, the mac in question, can't access that folder

It acesses everysingle other shared folder, no problem (he's the owner, so admin account) but that folder, it just can't.

It says it can't find the "can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found"

EDIT :

So more info on the problem.

I have 4 disks 
Boot/Win 
DATA 
Production 
Backups

There are multiple folders on DATA that are shared and the Mac acess it without problem. 
Recently we formated the PRODUCTION folder and fixed loose folders leaving only 6 folders

Production/a
Production/b
...

We then shared the HDD with EVERYONE.

Now the problem

The windows machines have no problem accessing that share and the sub folders, but the Mac just wont connect.

Is it a ntfs problem? If so why does it acess the DATA hdd without problems? I tried to install fuse but don't know what to do after installing it

Is it a shared the HDD problem? Should I share the inside folders instead?

To mention the Production folder is a 3tb folder ntfs gpt

Answer (score 1):

Accessing Window's shares on macOS is actually pretty simple but you must follow a couple of Windows login rules.

1. Set a username and password for the account you want to access the drive on that Windows server and give it the appropriate permissions on that server. It sounds like it should be in the Administrators group, but your choice.
2. When you connect to the PC from your Mac and it asks for a username and password you must "Fully Qualify" the username like this: [DOMAIN] \ [USERNAME]

I am assuming here that you are using an AD Domain account to access the Windows server which is Microsoft best practices for a Windows DC. For example.

Say I have a server in an AD (Active Directory) Domain and the domain is called "Americas." I would create the user I want in the Americas domain and give that account the appropriate permissions on the server in question. If we assume my AD username is "stevec" and my password is "123456" then I would log onto that server like this:

> Username: americas\stevec
>
> Password: 123456

For completeness sake if you need to access a server (or really any Windows PC) that is **not** in a domain you preface your username with the name (formerly called the NETBIOS name) of the PC on the network, a backslash, and then your username *on that PC*.

Comment: I can access other folders from the server without a problem. It's the acess to a specific folder, permissions are all set equally and still I can't acess it

Comment: If youir user is an Admin on the server log in to the server like this: SMB://[Server ip address]/x$  .  Where x is the drive letter of the drive you need to access on that server. That gets you into the root of that drive (the so called ADMIN share) if you can't access the folder then then your NTFS permissions on that drive might be messed up.